# Plot Area Gradient in MS Chart

Tags: c#, charts

I'm currently working with MS Chart for the first Time, and i want my C# Programm to draw a grey to white gradient under my graph, just like this (on the left is the current version, on the right what I want to do):

[image]

EDIT: Thank you Dmitry for including the Image from my Link :)

The only gradient Option I found for MS Chart so far is the Background.

This is my basic configuration of the chart so far:

```
chart.Series.Add(MsChartHelper.CreateSeries(chartData, SeriesChartType.Line));
chart.ChartAreas.Add(MsChartHelper.CreateChartArea());
chart.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
chart.Series[0].BorderColor = fnBlue;
chart.Series[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 92;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 96;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;                                  
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 36;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsInterlaced = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.InterlacedColor = fnGray;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

DataPoint min = chart.Series[0].Points.FindMinByValue();
min.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
min.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

DataPoint max = chart.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue();
max.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
max.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured out, how to achieve this. So if someone has the same Issue for some reason, this is how you do it:

Your Charttype hast to be Area

```
chart.Series.Add(MsChartHelper.CreateSeries(chartPlotData, SeriesChartType.Area));
```

After this, you can add a gradient and set a border color:

```
chart.Series[0].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
chart.Series[0].Color = Color.FromArgb(125, 110, 110, 110);
chart.Series[0].BackSecondaryColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
chart.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#AA3131");
chart.Series[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
chart.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
```

I hope this helps :)